# How to get default_id_categories from $params in a hook in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: parameters, module, prestashop, hook, prestashop-1.6

I´m creating a module and I need to capture the variable of the main category of each product that appear in the summary of the cart and for that I am using the hook displayBeforeShoppingCartBlock that appears above it. With print_r($params) I can see all the variables but it is very confusing to access the ones that interest me. Is there a simpler way to obtain these variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use this

```
public function hookDisplayBeforeShoppingCartBlock($params)
{
    $cart = new Cart($params['cart']->id);
    $cartProducts = $cart->getProducts();
}
```

the `$cartProducts` array will contain all products array with their `id_category_default` and you can access them with

```
foreach ($cartProducts as $product) {
    print_r($product['id_category_default']);
}
```

Comment: Im a newbie in the creation of modules for prestashop and you have given me a solution that can even helps me for other cases. Thank you very much!